# Hipay payment Gateway integration Response in php

Tags: php, payment-gateway

I'm using a hipay wallet test account and used there webservices to integrate. Transaction is working fine but problem is that i'm not getting the response in the page, it is suppossed to get in **$_POST['xml']** on the response page

> $setUrlAck =show_page_link("payment/hipay_new/response.php",true);

Below is my code

```
if ($PaymentDetails['sel_payment_env'] == 1) {
        $wsdl = 'https://ws.hipay.com/soap/subscription?wsdl'; //for live
    } else {
        $wsdl = 'https://test-ws.hipay.com/soap/subscription?wsdl';//for testing
    }
    // If the payment is accepted, the user will be redirected to this page
    $setURLOk= show_page_link(FILE_THANKS."?add=success&OrderNo=".$orderid,true);

    // If the payment is refused, the user will be redirected to this page
    $setUrlNok=show_page_link(FILE_THANKS."?cancleMsg=true",true);

    // If the user cancels the payment, he will be redirected to this page
    $setUrlCancel=show_page_link(FILE_THANKS."?cancleMsg=true",true);

    // The merchant?s site will be notified of the result of the payment by a call to the script
    $setUrlAck =show_page_link("payment/hipay_new/response.php",true); 

    $initArray = array(

            'wsLogin' => $wsLogin,              // Your wsLogin
            'wsPassword' => $wspassword,            // Your wsPassword
            'websiteId' => $txt_Merchant,           // Your webSiteId
            'categoryId' => $PaymentDetails['txt_category_id'],     // Your website category ID (https://test-payment.hipay.com/order/list-categories/id/(websiteId))
            'customerEmail' => $customer_email,                     // Your customers' email
    );
    $options = array(
            'compression' => SOAP_COMPRESSION_ACCEPT | SOAP_COMPRESSION_GZIP,
            'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    );

    $client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);
    $data = array(
            'currency' => $currency_code,
            'rating' => 'ALL',
            'locale' => 'fr_FR',
            'manualCapture' =>1,
            'label' => 'My label is a Manged Subscrption Test Service ',
            'customerIpAddress' => $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"],
            'merchantReference' => 'AZERTY',
            'urlCallback' => $setUrlAck, // Here in this page i'm suppossed to get the response in $_POST
            'urlAccept' => $setURLOk,
            'urlCancel' =>$setUrlCancel,
            'payments' => array(
                    'initial' => array(
                            'name' => 'Payment',
                            'description' => 'Payment for printing products',
                            'amount' => $price,
                            'subscriptionId' => 'QWERTY',
                            'periodType' => 'normal',
                            'recurrence' => array(
                                    'frequency' => 0,
                                    'duration' => 'managed'
                            ),
                    ),
            ),
    );
```

Kindly guide me if anyone got through the same issues

Comment: Please give me answer for this

Comment: The issue is solved, problem was that my firewall setting was blocking the response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is solved, problem was that my firewall setting was blocking the response